# Laravel 5.4 Implements interface MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Calendar Error

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, fullcalendar, laravel-5.4

Hello I have a problem with `MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Calendar`. I already try to look documentation and search in other question in stackoverflow but still didn't find the solution.

This is my eror :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Calendar::addEvent() must implement
>   interface MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event, array given, called in
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\isei\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 221

EventController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EventModel;
use App\Branch;
use Calendar;
use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event;

class EventController extends Controller
{
  public function getIndex()
  {
     $event = [];
     $data = EventModel::all();
     if($data->count())
     {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
          $event[] = Calendar::event(
              $value->title,
              true,
              new \DateTime($value->start_date),
              new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day')
          );
        }
     }

    $calendar = \Calendar::addEvent($event);
    return view('event', compact('calendar'));
  }
}
```

Event Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EventModel extends Model implements \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\IdentifiableEvent
{
  protected $table = 'event';
  protected  $fillable = [
    'id_branch','title','start_date','end_date'
  ];

  public function cabang()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Branch', 'id', 'id_branch');
  }

  protected $dates = ['start', 'end'];

    /**
     * Get the event's id number
     *
     * @return int
     */
  public function getId()
  {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the event's title
     *
     * @return string
     */
  public function getTitle()
  {
        return $this->title;
  }

    /**
     * Is it an all day event?
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllDay()
    {
        return (bool)$this->all_day;
    }

    /**
     * Get the start time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Get the end time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change:

```
use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event;
```

at your `EventController` to this:

```
use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

add s to addEvent

```
$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($event);
```